# set a breakpoint after generating a response by the server and before sending it to the client

Tags: http, https, response, breakpoints, fiddler

In Fiddler there is methods such as **OnBeforeRequest** and **OnBeforeResponse**. I want to send request to the server and I want the server to generate a response but I don't want to receive the response. I want to set a breakpoint before the server sends back  the response (a breakpoint should be after generating the response and before sending it).
I've tried to write a custom rule but wasn't really successful.

I would appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OnBeforeResponse, set `oSession["x-BreakResponse"] = "yup";`

https://www.telerik.com/amp/blogs/breakpoints-in-fiddler